# Extracting all API calls from .smali files in android apk

Tags: android, smali

I want to extract all API calls from an Android application's apk. I have used apktool to get the smali code files from the apk. Manually I can spot some API calls, but I need an automated method. For example, I can see the `getNetworkInfo` call in this line of code:

```
    invoke-virtual {p0, v0}, Landroid/net/ConnectivityManager;->getNetworkInfo(I)Landroid/net/NetworkInfo;
```

I have no experience with smali code and very little with Android application analysis; I only spotted the above API call because I happened to know that "getNetworkInfo" is one. But of course, what I don't want to do is begin with a list of all possible API calls and search for each of them in the smali files one by one.

Is there another indication of an API call? Will `invoke-virtual` or `invoke-direct` will always mean an API call?

Comment: I would recommend using dexlib2 to access the dex file programatically, rather than trying to parse the smali files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`invoke-virtual` and `invoke-direct` just call a method of some object with and without virtual method resolution, respectively.  This doesn't necessarily have to be an API call; you could use these instructions with any kind of object, including instances of classes you define in your own code.

In this case, you found a call to a method in the `android.net.ConnectivityManager` class.  If you want to find more API calls, you could start by searching for `invoke-*` instructions that reference certain classes, which for example might include anything under `android.*`, `java.*`, `javax.*`, etc.